# One line recursive loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, recursion

I want to rewrite this function to regular loop:

```
def combine(n,k):
    if k == 0:
        return [[]]

    return [pre + [i] for i in range(1, n + 1) for pre in combine(i - 1, k - 1)]
```

Cause I can't debug each step of the loop. For example, what does **pre** store in an internal loop?

**Here is a task**:
Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers out of 1 ... n.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What did you try?

Comment: Call it with increasing values and print the results?

Comment: That is a [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html#list-comprehensions), and it appears to me that your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list comprehension at the heart of this function is building up an implicit list that ultimately gets returned.  We can unwind the function, remove the comprehension, and use an explicit list:

```
def combine(n, k):
    """
    Given two integers n and k, return all possible
    combinations of k numbers out of 1 ... n.
    """

    result = []

    if k == 0:
        result.append([])
    else:
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            for pre in combine(i - 1, k - 1):
                result.append(pre + [i])

    return result

print(combine(7, 4))
```

> what does **pre** store in an internal loop?

The `pre` variable store individual elements of the recursion.  For example, to get all four digit combinations of seven digits, the code uses recursion to calculate all the three digit combinations and then augments them.  That elements of that recursive result, each three digit combination, is stored, in turn, in `pre`.